# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and Linear inependence and $\cos \theta$

Tags: linear-algebra

For the angle between two vectors, if $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent can the $\cos\theta = 1$ or $-1$?

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\mathbf x^T\mathbf y}{||\mathbf x||\;||\mathbf y||}$$

Answer (score 0):

$x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=0$ or $y=0$ or 
$$
|\cos\theta|=\frac{|x^Ty|}{\|x\|\|y\|}=1.
$$